# Why does it bring repeat items from other purchases when I use max(last price)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I'm banging my head to understand why my query doesn't work as expected.
I have two tables: shopping table and products table.
I need to extract the last purchase of the item based on what I have available in stock (for stock valuation).

I tried that, but I understand that it's not bringing only the last purchase because it brings me repeated items.

```sql
SELECT T0.ItemCode, T0.Dscription, 
        MAX(T0.Currency)[Currency], 
        MAX(T0.Price)[Price], T1.OnHand[in stock], 
        MAX(T0.U_Processo)[Customs process]
FROM Order_Lines T0 RIGHT 
      JOIN Items T1 ON T0.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode
WHERE T0.ItemCode NOT LIKE '%%DESP-%%' 
      AND T0.ItemCode = (SELECT TOP 1 T1.ItemCode WHERE T1.OnHand > 0) 
      AND T0.U_Processo IS NOT NULL /*I used this information because it 
                                      was also repeated when the item does not have 
                                      this information and when it has this information. 
                                      MAX() does not work.*/
GROUP BY T0.ItemCode, T0.Dscription, T1.OnHand, T0.U_Processo
ORDER BY T0.ItemCode
```

**Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?**

Oh! I even noticed a few times that it's bringing me more than once when it's paid in two different currencies, so I put the MAX() in the currency too, but I don't know if it can. I even did the same thing for customs processes.

**PS. I Tryed to use MAX(Date), but don't work too**

This is an example:

| ItemCode | Dscription | Currency | Price | in Stock | Customs Process |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I0028015A-001 | ECLISSE TABLE LAMP 110V | EUR | 92.150000 | 5.000000 | PQU 20-045 |
| I0028035A-001 | ECLISSE TABLE LAMP 110V | EUR | 92.150000 | 4.000000 | PQU 20-045 |

Comment: To add to John Cappelletti's comment which is certainly correct, when you group by onhand, that allows for records having different values of that column to show up the result. Since you aliased that to "in Stock" it masks the column name it is easy to overlook.

Comment: My guess is including T1.OnHand in the Group By is causing the issue.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti the problem if I exclude the T1.OnHand, the SQL claim I need to include in the group by. "Column 'OnHand' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in an aggregate function or GROUP BY clause." And if I add the "T1.OnHand > 0" SQL also complains

Comment: @RobertHamilton How I to make this? thanks

Comment: @FarleyASouza Exactly.   In any aggregation query every column is either  an aggregation or included in the GROUP BY.   The question is, what do you ant to do with ONHAND ?   Average? Last Value ?  Or just remove it all together.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti (1) Oh! Now I get it! Onhand is a field that saves the quantity available in stock. As I need to have the full valuation in stock, I thought "Bring me the latest purchase orders, but only for the products I have in stock." I thought doing it this way would bring me the last purchase based on the total item I have in stock. Continue....

Comment: @JohnCappelletti (2)... For example, I have 10 purchase orders with 1 item(itemcode) and varying quantity in each order, but currently I only have 5 quantities of that item in stock(onhand = 5). And the first order is from 2015 and the last order is from 2021. I would like to know the updated value of this item (last purchase price). That is, Itemcode, price (from the purchase table) and quantity (from the item table). I don't know if I explained it right. I appreciate the attention and help you are giving me.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Done! I did the opposite! What a shame! hahahaha 

```
SELECT T0.ItemCode, T0.ItemName, T0.OnHand, x.preco, x.moeda, x.Taxa, x.processo 
FROM OITM T0 
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT T1.ItemCode, MAX(T1.Price) as preco, MAX(T1.Currency) as moeda, MAX(T1.Rate) as Taxa,
        MAX(T1.U_Processo) as processo, MAX(T1.DocDate) as UltData 
      FROM POR1 T1     
      GROUP BY T1.ItemCode
      ) x ON T0.ItemCode = X.ItemCode
WHERE T0.OnHand > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to correct the way I was fetching the data.
I'm answering here so you can be registered.

```
SELECT T0.ItemCode, T0.ItemName, T0.OnHand, x.preco, x.moeda, x.Taxa, x.processo 
FROM Items T0 
            LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT T1.ItemCode, MAX(T1.Price) as preco, MAX(T1.Currency) as moeda, MAX(T1.Rate) as Taxa,
                                MAX(T1.U_Process) as processo, MAX(T1.DocDate) as UltData 
                        FROM Purchase_Lines T1                  
                        GROUP BY T1.ItemCode
                        ) x ON T0.ItemCode = X.ItemCode
WHERE T0.OnHand > 0
```

**Tks for @JohnCappelletti and @RobertHamilton for help me!**